# Registration auto login disable

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I am using keycloak 4.8.3 Final for my project. I need to disable auto login after the registration. I have been reading keycloak documentation for 5 days. Couldn't find the answer, i dont know if it's possible or not. Any guide will be useful for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to show the Keycloak login form again after the registration, you can setup as follows:

1. Go to *Authentication* settings and select *Registration* flow.
2. Click *Copy* button.
3. Click *Add execution* button and select *Username Password Form*.
4. Click *REQUIRED* checkbox of *Username Password Form* execution.
5. Click *Bindings* tab and change *Registration Flow* to the copied registration flow.
6. Click *Save* button.

[image]

Comment: This shouldn't be the answer as it's just a workaround. By adding this execution, the active Registration flow will still not change to the Login (Browser) Flow but will just render the login form. Any other executions that you have within the Login Flow won't be executed... It's a pity that Keycloak doesn't allow you to easily check a box if you want the user to be automatically logged in or not.